# Can i turn the CIFAR-10 dataset to grayscale images and convert it to same dimension as MNIST dataset. Will the model be invalid or fail to learn?

Tags: theano, deep-learning, caffe

I'm new in the field of Deep Neural Network. There are various deep learning frameworks nearby. Notably `Theano`, `Torch7`, `Caffe`, and recently open sourced `TensorFlow`. I have tried out a couple of tutorials with `TensorFlow` provided on their site. Specifically the `MNIST dataset`. I guess this is the `hello world` of every deep learning framework out there. I also viewed tutorials from [here](http://cs231n.stanford.edu). This one was explained in detail, but they do not provide hands on experience with any deep learning frameworks. So which framework should be better for beginners? I looked up similar questions asked on Quora. Some said that theano is tougher to learn but it gives more control, Caffe is easier, but it gives less control over the network. And nothing on Tensorflow, as it is new, but from what i've seen the documentation is not That well written, also it seems tougher to understand. So as a newbie what should i choose to learn?

Another question, As I said, MNIST is the `hello world` of every deep learning framework, and many neural networks can be found for recognizing `MNIST` dataset. So, if I use the same network to detect other dataset, say `CIFAR-10` dataset, will it work?? Let's just say that i turn the `CIFAR-10` dataset to grayscale images and convert it to same dimension as MNIST dataset. Will the model be invalid or fail to learn? or have bad accuracy or what?

Comment: imho question should be which implementation is faster. You can learn whatever you want, when you have enough time. Have you look at keras,  scikit-neuralnetwork or Pylearn2 - maybe it will be easier to learn.

Comment: Software library recommendations are off topic for StackOverflow and your question about CIFAR-10 would require too much background information to explain to a newbie. I suggest you work through more tutorials. BTW, Theano may be more difficult to learn but it will force you to understand the principles and underlying mechanisms at work which may well benefit you in the future.

Comment: so can't i convert CIFAR-10 images to MNIST so easily?? or if i can will it produce any difference in accuracy??

Comment: You might want to look into DIGITS - https://developer.nvidia.com/digits.

Comment: Do u know any reference or any tutorial that can help me apply deep learning with CIFAR-10 datasets using theano??

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question? I'm trying to find the same thing right now

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 pixel maps for each "filter" color: red, green, and blue. A simple way to get grayscale is to simply pick one of the colors and ignore the other two. Such would probably make the images harder to identify for both people and bots.

A fancier way is to average the pixel values of all 3 color planes into a single plane (grayscale). This would probably make for more recognizable images than the first method, but less so than the full-color ones.